# JAXB exception while trying to deploy .war to GlassFish 3.1.2

Tags: jaxb, glassfish

> Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Provider com.sun.xml.bind.ContextFactory_1_0_1 could not be instantiated: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
>    - with linked exception:
>   [java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: theInstance]

Looks like there is some kind of JAXB dependency conflict. How can i ensure? Has anyone faced with problems like this? Any suggestions? 
Thanks.